Removing a character from [index] for index in the indexlist
I am making a simple search function which searches word matches from a list of words. Characters in the searchword should be replaceable with a ".". I, however, ran into trouble with slicing strings with a for-loop.
Green part which removes the dots from searchword (hakusana) seems to work just fine, but using the indexes to remove characters from words in a searchpool (sanalista) marked in red only removes one character instead of the required amount. enter image description here The lines hakusana =  hakusana[:i] + hakusana[i + 1:] and apusana = apusana[:i] + apusana[i + 1:] look in essence the same to me, so is the problem with the for-loop, which i am using? It is supposed to remove a character from [index] for index in the indexlist.
    if "." in hakusana:
        indeksit = []
        while hakusana.count(".") > 0:
            i = hakusana.index(".")
            hakusana =  hakusana[:i] + hakusana[i + 1:]
            indeksit.append(i + len(indeksit))
        for sana in sanalista:
            if len(hakusana) + len(indeksit) == len(sana):
                apusana = sana
                for i in indeksit:
                    apusana = apusana[:i] + apusana[i + 1:]
                if apusana == hakusana:
                    osumat.append(sana)


After deleting a character, following characters move one position to the left.

Your code seems to make very little sense - it would help if you provided an example value for hakusana and sanalista and what the expected resulting osumat would be.

@Grismar: it's a suboptimal way of doing things, but I wanted to try and use slicing in this assingment just to learn about it. Example value for hakusana could be ".a." in which case it would append words like [car, car, oar,...] from the sanalista (list of words) into osumat (list of matches) and return all the matches. Optimally I should probably have used a code like if hakusana[i] != "." and hakusana[i] != sana[i]: in a loop. To eliminate words that are not matches. Thanks for your feedback.

@Arttu You should probably take a look at regular expressions (re module) for the pattern matching

It's not a criticism of it being suboptimal - I'm serious about the fact that it's unclear what you're trying to do from the code alone. Please show how you call it, or what the values of the used variables are and explain what you expect the values to be at the end. Without that, the question is unclear.
